Angular CDK Overlay not displaying in MatAutocomplete and Overlay basic example
I was trying to get autocomplete to work but it refused to display except once which I cannot replicate. Then tried tried designing something similar using the Overlay basic example but still not working.


<!-- styles.scss -->
@import '../../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/cyan-orange.css'; 
@import "../../../node_modules/@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css";
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100">
        <mat-label i18n>Tags</mat-label>
        <mat-chip-grid #tagsChipList>
            @for (tag of tagsSignal(); track tag.id) {
                <mat-chip-row
                  matChipRemove
                  [removable]="true"
                  (removed)="onRemoveTag(tag)"
                >
                  {{ tag.name }}
                  <button matChipRemove [attr.aria-label]="'remove ' + tag.name">
                      <mat-icon>cancel</mat-icon>
                  </button>
               </mat-chip-row>
           }
        <input
          #tagInput
          name="close-outline"
          [matChipInputFor]="tagsChipList"
          [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
          [matAutocomplete]="autocompleteTags"
          [(ngModel)]="currentTag"
          (matChipInputTokenEnd)="onAddTagInput()"
          />
      </mat-chip-grid>
      <mat-autocomplete
        class="autocomplete cdk-overlay-container"
        #autocompleteTags="matAutocomplete"
        (optionSelected)="onAddTag($event)"
       >
        @for (tag of filteredTags(); track tag.id) {
            <mat-option [value]="tag.id">
              {{ tag.name }}
            </mat-option>
        }
        </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>






best is create stackbliz or any other place test project and share that or share error that you received on console on development mode.
